# Retrieving NSDate from Core Data

Tags: ios, nsdate

I am attempting to retrieve the latest NSdate entry from core data. The way I am attempting to do so is to sort by date and get the `objectAtIndex`. I am however struggling to retrieve the result and am getting it returned as `nil`. I presuming my issue is around `NSDate *obj = [results objectAtIndex:0];` though I am not sure how to fix it. Any suggestions will be welcomed. I could be well off the mark so excuse me if I am.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Get Reference to App Delegate
    SSAppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    //Fetch Entity
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]
                              initWithEntityName:@"RecentDetails"];
    //Sort By Date
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
    //Store In Array
     NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:NULL];

/////////////NEEDS EXTRA HERE ACCORDING TO COMMENTS


    //Find Object at Index 0
    NSDate *obj = [results objectAtIndex:0];
    //Set Batch Size
    [request setFetchBatchSize:1];

    //NSDate Formatter
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"ddMMyyyy"];

    //Convert to string
    NSString *stringFromDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:obj];

    //Test Log
    NSLog(@"Latest Date! %@", stringFromDate);

}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code in which you save a date?

Comment: Lots of possible issues here depending on the rest of the code, but it should be pointed out that [results objectAtIndex:0] will give you an entity object of "RecentDetails" and not just a date, so you'll have to account for that first and foremost. Sort is just going to order the results for you.

Comment: updated question. I know it is getting inputted correctly as I have used it in a predicate.

Comment: What does dateLabel.currentTitle return?

Comment: I am using a `uidatepicker` and setting the value on a `uibutton` which is `datelabel.currentTitle`

Comment: @AlbaClan: You should read Stakenborg's comment again. It explains exactly what you are doing wrong.

Comment: @MartinR Can I asked a stupid question. What should I be doing between there?

Comment: Use NSLog to see if the dateLabel.currentText is not nil.

Comment: AS previously mentioned @AbdullahShafique the data is entered correctly into my core data entity.

Comment: Apart from the obvious errors, where are you getting the nil? Also, you are running a fetch request, but not checking to see if you have any results. A fetch request that returns an empty array means that not results have been found. A fetch request than returns nil indicates an error, in which case you should be checking the error parameter. Setting it to NULL, doesn't help you or the people trying to help you.

Comment: @Abizern I have already checked to see if it is returning results and it is so I excluded the code to make it clearer in the question. I am getting nil in the NSLOG

Comment: Have you fixed the problem that everyone is telling you about? You're trying to format an object of type `RecentDetails` not the date attribute of that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When inserting, change:

  ```
  NSManagedObjectContext *recentDetails = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"RecentDetails"inManagedObjectContext:context];
  ```

  to:

  ```
  NSManagedObject *recentDetails = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"RecentDetails"inManagedObjectContext:context];`
  ```
- When retrieving, like pointed out by Stakenborg, you should be getting your date property from an entity object of "RecentDetails".
- `[request setFetchBatchSize:1]` should be set prior to `[context executeFetchRequest:request...]`, otherwise it has no effect on amount of RecentDetails objects fetched.

Comment: Hi @arseniy ..... Its the `getting your date property from an entity object` that Im confused about. Should I just be doing a `NSpredicate`?

Comment: `stringFromDate:obj.date`

Comment: this is confusing me greatly. I am getting Property `'date' not found on object of type 'NSDate *'`

Comment: @AlbaClan, you typically use NSPredicate to define logical conditions for retrieving entity objects, i.e. "RecentDetails" in your case. Since the "sort then get the first" approach is sufficient for that already, you can just take the date property like that: `RecentDetails *recentDetails = (RecentDetails *)[results objectAtIndex:0];` `NSDate *theDate = recentDetails.date;`

Comment: Brillant got it working. Thank you everyone who helped out - @Abizern and Arseniy